# Is it possible to load learned model (.t7) on TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, torch

I have learned model of CNN(`model.t7`) and I want to use this model on another Python-base deep learning framework(for example, TensorFlow).

Could you tell me how to achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. you could save the model parameters in the format of numpy(*.npy) because tf supports numpy you could load the trained parameter via loading npy files. Of course, it will take times since it implement via third-part package.

Answer (score 5):

There are some scripts/libraries out there.

Here you can find an overview: https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor

In your case you would need to convert:

1. From Torch to pyTorch https://github.com/clcarwin/convert_torch_to_pytorch
2. From pyTorch to Tensorflow (over Keras) https://github.com/nerox8664/pytorch2keras

But read the limitations beforehand since not all operations are supported.